# Fast moving an item in Microsoft Visio 2013

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-visio-2013

Upon selecting an item in Microsoft Visio, is there any way to move it more quickly than when pressing on one arrow key (or increase the default speed)?

E.g.

[image]

I'd like to move it faster, but without drag and drop, and without having to specify the destination coordinates.

I use Microsoft Visio 2013 Professional on Windows 7.

Comment: I think that you can't move it faster. Is there a method to move faster objects in other Office 2013 products ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of but Office contains so many features I might have missed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no available option in Visio 2013 to change the speed when moving a selected object with the keyboard arrows (<kbd>→</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>...)